# Looking for text list merge program

Tags: windows, text-editor, text-processing, user-interface

I'm looking for a program that can combine several lists.

Must be Windows supported, completely free or freemium, has an interface and unicode supported. It should be able to add prefix, suffix and delimiter.

I have a website for the example. It matches the features I want, but it has usage restriction.

[Example Site](https://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/merge-text-line-line/)

Comment: It is good task for CudaText editor plugin, you can ask this at support forum or  Github. Eg, the example site can be made as plugin.

Comment: @RProgram Could be. I will do.